# Node JS Post keeps loading and not redirecting in a simple form

Tags: javascript, node.js

**I'm new to Node and creating a simple form but I can't post using form in html but I can post in the rest client extension in vs code.**

**my index.js:**

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express=require('express')
const app=express()
const mongoose=require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL,{ useUnifiedTopology: true , useNewUrlParser: true } )
const db=mongoose.connection
db.on('error',()=>console.error(error))
db.once('open',()=>console.log('welcome to the database'))
app.use(express.json())
const authRoute=require('./routes/auth')
app.use('/auth',authRoute)
app.listen(3000,()=>console.log('welcome to the server'))
```

**routes in auth**

```
 const express=require('express')
    const app=express()
    const router=express.Router()
    const bcrypt=require('bcryptjs');
    const Human=require('../model/human')
    app.set('view-engine','ejs')
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))
    //register
    router.get('/register',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('register.ejs')
    
    })
    router.post('/register',async(req,res)=>{
        const hashedpass=await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password,10)
        const newHuman=new Human({
            name:req.body.name,
            email:req.body.email,
            password:hashedpass
        })
        try{
            await newHuman.save()
            res.redirect('/auth/login')
        }catch(err){
            res.send('errorr')
        }
        
    })
```

**here is the register form**

```
<h1>Register</h1>
<form method="POST" action="/auth/register">
    <div>
        <label for="name">name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required></input>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">register</button>
</form>
<a href="/auth/login"></a>
```

**Where did I go wrong? I think I lack a middleware in the form or something because as i said it works in the rest client extension**
**here is the error**:(node:8680) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8680) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: The form action points to `/auth/register` while the server listens for posts on `/register`

Comment: no sorry for not clarifying that.my index.js haves const authRoute=require('./routes/auth')
app.use('/auth',authRoute) and the register is in auth route

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: can you show your app.js code please?

Comment: I updated the question again

Comment: @LesterKingsley in your `.post` router. Place `console.log("1")` and so on for each line of code.. 1,2,3 and when you click the button, which numbers is not showing on the output?

Comment: "Human validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., email: Path `email` is required., password: Path `password` is required." i get this in my browser when i remove bcrypt.has

Comment: i change all to string  name:"user 1",
        email:"lalala@email.com",
        password:"1222333" and it works so the req is not working

Comment: do you see any new error ? does it still keep loading ? or it redirects?

Comment: I finally found the answer man, the body parser has been updated to express in july 8, I installed seperately and put it as a middleware in the post and it works.And thanks I won't identify the problem if I haven't notice it is occurring in the parsing

Answer (score 1):

**I finally found the answer, it is because of the new update,install the new body parser(now seperate from express) and put the urlencodedparser to the post**

```
 const express=require('express')
    const app=express()
    const router=express.Router()
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    const bcrypt=require('bcryptjs')
    const Human=require('../model/human')
    app.set('view-engine','ejs')
    
    var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    
    //register
    router.get('/register',async(req,res)=>{
        try{
        res.render('register.ejs')
        }catch(err){
                res.json(err.message)
        }
    })
    router.post('/register',urlencodedParser,async(req,res)=>{
    
        const hashedpass=await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password,10)
        try{
        
            const newHuman=new Human({
                name:req.body.name,
                email:req.body.email,
                password:hashedpass
            })
           const hum= await newHuman.save()
           console.log(hum)
            res.json(hum)
        }catch(err){
            res.json(err.message)
        }
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form action points to a route called `/register`, but your HTML form points to `/auth/register`.

Comment: it is already in the route of auth. sorry for not clarifying that.